# Can't insert into table after CAST(SUBSTR(column,8,6) as number(6))

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table where I inserted my fixed file data to single `varchar2` column and called this table `tmp_table`

```
CREATE TABLE "tmp_table" 
   (    "COLUMN1" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE)
   )
```

Now I am trying to transform and insert data from this `tmp_table` to final `table` where I am breaking the data using `SUBSTR` function

Now I created my next table where I will insert these columns

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE" 
   (
    "COLUMN A" VARCHAR2(4),
    "CODE" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "DATE_LOADED_TIMESTAMP" DATE
   )
```

Now I run a select query to check if I can get right data from my `tmp_table` that I want to insert to final `TABLE`

So I run the query

```
SELECT Cast(SUBSTR(COLUMN1,8,6)as number(6)) as Code
from TMP_TABLE;
```

The results I see were good and what I want to insert into `CODE` column.

Now I try to run final query:

```
insert into TABLE(CODE) 
SELECT Cast(SUBSTR(COLUMN1,8,6)as number(6)) as Code
from TMP_TABLE;
```

Now it gives me error

```
Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Why am I not able to insert number values to a 6 digit number column?

Comment: possible that there are values in your database which are not a number in the result of the substring?

Comment: @Jens If there were values which were not number I should get a error when I ran the select statement but I got no errors running the select statement which means I was successfully able to covert those values to number.

Comment: @Auguster . . . Not necessarily.  If you are using an interface like Toad, then you are just seeing one small batch of rows at a time.

Comment: Try running `select * from tmp_table where regexp_instr(substr(column1, 8,6), '[^0-9]') > 0;` to detect rows with non-numeric values.

Comment: @kfinity  I tried that and found the answer I have characters. Thanks guys

Comment: One way to force SQL Developer to inspect all the rows is to use an aggregate - perhaps `select sum(cast(....)) as sum_code from tmp_table`. This would only be a first check, to confirm that the problem is in the `column1` data and not elsewhere; the `REGEXP_LIKE` thing (what kfinity proposed is **better** than what you wrote, since it will catch spaces, colons etc., not just letters) will tell you exactly which values are invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found what happened I was using SQL Developer and the query I ran below was returning on some results in my tool and the few results it was showing there was no characters in those fields.

```
SELECT Cast(SUBSTR(COLUMN1,8,6)as number(6)) as Code
from TMP_TABLE;
```

I ran following query to search if there are characters in the records I am looking at:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN1,8,6)
from TMP_TABLE
where REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(COLUMN1,8,6),'[A-Za-z]');
```

and here I saw characters now I know not to trust SQL developer blindly :)

Comment: SQL Developer will fetch rows from the database in batches and if the query on that batch has no exceptions then it will be displayed to the user. A later batch may throw an exception. You can configure the size of batch in `Tools > Preferences > Database > Advanced > Sql Array Fetch Size`.